# orainvalidnumbererrorin sql

Tags: sql

I have this below code where I am trying to take the sum of all the values. But I am getting invalid number error.

```
select 
     sum (
           DECODE (
              a.billed_uom,
              'kW', DECODE (
                       a.multiplier,
                       'N/A', 0,
                       ' ', 0,
                       DECODE (a.billed_usage, ' ', 0, a.billed_usage)),
              'kVA', DECODE (
                        a.multiplier,
                        'N/A', 0,
                        ' ', 0,
                        DECODE (a.billed_usage, ' ', 0, a.billed_usage)),
              0))
           AS billed_kw_kva    

             FROM zbi_s_metrdetail a WHERE billing_doc <> ' ' ;
```

when I take sum of values of top 100 records, I am getting the results. There is some bug in the values. How do I get rid of that?
The data looks like this :

[image]

Below is the column definition :

```
BILLED_USAGE    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes     28  
BILLED_UOM      VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)    Yes     29  
MULTIPLIER      VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)   Yes     14
```

Comment: Proper formatting makes SQL so much easier to read. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. BTW, which dbms are you using?

Comment: When StackOverflow doesn't allow you to name your question "ORA Invalid Number Error in SQL" the reasoning behind this is that this has been asked and answered many times + this doesn't really describe your problem. Removing spaces to put in the title isn't the way to go ...

Comment: I'm not sure, but your Result should be varchar, right? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm
So when you are writing `DECODE (a.billed_usage, ' ', 0, a.billed_usage)` the `0` should be `'0'`.

Comment: @Nebi - I tried that but no luck

Comment: Did you do that for all the 0's? Else try not to do the whole thing, but every DECODE for itself. Beginning the inner most.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the data!  Find the values that are not correct:

```
select billed_usage
from zbi_s_metrdetail
where not regexp_like(billed_usage, '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$')
```

and

```
select multipler
from zbi_s_metrdetail
where not regexp_like(multipler, '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$')
```

When you find the bad values, fix them!